# Lost ability to edit CMS, products & attributes after upgrading from 2.1.2 to 2.1.3

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, magento-2.1.3

After upgrading to Magento 2.1.3 using composer I have lost the ability to edit anything. When I click to edit or create products, CMS pages, attributes etc. it simply doesn't show anything to allow editing.

Everything worked perfectly before the upgrade and I have tried deleting cache & static files as well as compiling, redepolying static content, etc.

Other people also seem to have this issue, see GitHub:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7834

Any help greatly appreciated otherwise I am going to have to do a complete wipe and reinstall.

Comment: Any errors in the browser console or var/log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this myself.

There wasn't a problem with the Magento 2 install, the problem was that the upgrade caused some sort of issue with my browser (Mac OS, Safari). I tried logging in with another device and it all worked perfectly so I cleared my browser cache, cookies and website data for this site and I'm able to log in perfectly.

It's very strange that upgrading would cause this problem but I had a similar issue after a complete reinstall of Magento 2 some time ago.

Hopefully this will help others who are having the same problem.